Assign user role "view users" with keycloak
When I create a user, and then I want to start my application with this user, the user needs to have this role:

How can I assign this role to my user_id? And why is this necessary?

How can I assign this role to my user_id?
You can assign role by REST API
Tricky part is you need to know {realm-management_id} and {view-users_role_id}
The assign-role.js shows how to get those IDs
REST API Endpoint
POST /admin/realms/{my-realm}/users/{user_id}/role-mappings/clients/{realm-management_id}

Body
[
   {
      "id":{view-users_role_id},
      "name":"view-users",
      "description":"${role_view-users}"
    }
]

Token : master token or realm admin's token
Example by Postman

Example by node.js
Save as assign-role.js
// assign-role.js
const axios = require('axios');

const getMasterToken = async (user_name, password) => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.post(
            'http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token',
            new URLSearchParams({
                'client_id': 'admin-cli',
                'username': user_name,
                'password': password,
                'grant_type': 'password'
            })
        );
        return resp.data.access_token;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

const getUser = async (token, username) => {
    try {
        const config = {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
        };
        const url = `http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/my-realm/users/?username=${encodeURIComponent(username)}`;
        const response = await axios.get(url, config);

        if (response.status === 200) {
            return response.data;
        } else {
            console.error(`Failed to fetch user: Server responded with status ${response.status}`);
            return null;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            console.error('Server responded with status:', error.response.status);
            console.error('Response data:', error.response.data);
        } else if (error.request) {
            console.error('No response received:', error.request);
        } else {
            console.error('Error setting up request:', error.message);
        }
        return null;
    }
};


const getClient = async (token, clientName) => {
    try {
        const config = {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
        };
        const url = `http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/my-realm/clients/?clientId=${clientName}`;
        const response = await axios.get(url, config);

        if (response.status === 200) {
            return response.data;
        } else {
            console.error(`Failed to fetch client: Server responded with status ${response.status}`);
            return null;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            console.error('Server responded with status:', error.response.status);
            console.error('Response data:', error.response.data);
        } else if (error.request) {
            console.error('No response received:', error.request);
        } else {
            console.error('Error setting up request:', error.message);
        }
        return null;
    }
};

const assignRole = async (token, userId, clientId, payload) => {
    try {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
        const url = `http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/my-realm/users/${userId}/role-mappings/clients/${clientId}`;
        const response = await axios.post(url, payload, config);

        if (response.status === 204) { // Status 204 No Content means the request was successful but the server is not returning any content
            return true;
        } else {
            console.error(`Failed to assign roles: Server responded with status ${response.status}`);
            return false;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            console.error('Server responded with status:', error.response.status);
            console.error('Response data:', error.response.data);
        } else if (error.request) {
            console.error('No response received:', error.request);
        } else {
            console.error('Error setting up request:', error.message);
        }
        return false;
    }
};

const getClientRole = async (token, clientId, roleName) => {
    try {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        };
        const url = `http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/my-realm/clients/${clientId}/roles`;
        const response = await axios.get(url, config);

        if (response.status === 200 && response.data) {
            // Filter roles to find one that matches the roleName
            const role = response.data.find(r => r.name === roleName);
            return role || null; // Return the role if found, or null if not found
        } else {
            console.error(`Failed to fetch roles: Server responded with status ${response.status}`);
            return null;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            console.error('Server responded with status:', error.response.status);
            console.error('Response data:', error.response.data);
        } else if (error.request) {
            console.error('No response received:', error.request);
        } else {
            console.error('Error setting up request:', error.message);
        }
        return null;
    }
};

(async () => {

    const master_token = await getMasterToken('admin', 'admin');

    const userName = 'user1';
    const userData = await getUser(master_token, 'user1');
    const userId = (userData) ? userData[0].id : null;

    if (userData) {
        console.log(`${userName} User ID:`, userId);
    }

    const clientName = 'realm-management';
    const clientData = await getClient(master_token, clientName);
    const clientId = (clientData) ? clientData[0].id : null;

    if (clientData) {
        console.log(`${clientName} Client ID:`, clientId);
    } else {
        console.error('Failed to fetch client data or client does not exist');
    }

    const roleName = "view-users";
    const role = await getClientRole(master_token, clientId, roleName);
    if (role) {
        const rolePayload = [{
            "id": `${role.id}`,
            "name": `${role.name}`,
            "description": `${role.description}`
        }];
        const result = await assignRole(master_token, userId, clientId, rolePayload);

        if (result) {
            console.log('Role assignment successful');
        } else {
            console.error('Failed to assign roles');
        }
    } else {
        console.error('Failed to get role');
    }
})();

Install Dependency
npm install axios

Run it
node assign-role.js

Result


Why is this necessary?
That user can get the users list by REST API
If not has a view-users role, can't get the user list.
I will demo
user1 can get the user list
user2 can't get the user list, He will get 403 error
Save as get-users.js
// get-users.js
const axios = require('axios');

const getUserToken = async (user_name, password) => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.post(
            'http://localhost:8080/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token',
            new URLSearchParams({
                'client_id': 'admin-cli',
                'username': user_name,
                'password': password,
                'grant_type': 'password'
            })
        );
        return resp.data.access_token;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

const getUsers = async (token) => {
    try {
        const config = {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
        };
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/my-realm/users', config);
        
        if (response.status === 200) {
            console.log('Successfully fetched users.');
            return response.data; // Return user data if response is successful
        } else {
            console.error(`Failed to fetch users: Server responded with status ${response.status}`);
            return null; // Return null or an appropriate value indicating the error
        }
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            console.error('Server responded with status:', error.response.status);
            console.error('Response data:', error.response.data);
        } else if (error.request) {
            console.error('No response received:', error.request);
        } else {
            console.error('Error setting up request:', error.message);
        }
        return null; // Return null or an appropriate value indicating the error
    }
};

(async () => {
    const username = process.argv[2];
    const password = process.argv[3];
    
    const user_token = await getUserToken(username, password);
    const users = await getUsers(user_token);
    console.log('Users: ', users);
})();

User1 result

User2 result

